# com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error when i invoke POST method call

Tags: java, spring-cloud-netflix

**Forwarding error: **

When i call my POST microservices through angularjs + Zuul + hystrix  it shows forwarding exception. But if i make a call through client REST API or POSTMAN it provides the success message as `200 OK` status.

> 2017-04-24 19:09:50.315  WARN 6196 --- [nio-9090-exec-6] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
>
> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:157) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:132) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:78) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
>       Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: crudoperations timed-out and no fallback available.
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:805) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:789) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:139) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1494) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1384) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:313) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:305) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:141) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:953) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:970) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
>           ... 1 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:600) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:580) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:139) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
>           ... 15 common frames omitted

Comment: Have a closer look at this message: `Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: crudoperations timed-out and no fallback available. at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:805)`  Try checking what is missing from your angular request that makes it routed elsewhere.

Comment: What is your problem? Please include the actual question you're asking (e.g. "Why does this happen?" or "How can I fix this?"). Also, you provide little more than the error message, which makes it very difficult for us to help you. Please also include some code/more details about your case.

Answer (score 5):

As I recall, the default hystrix command timeout is 1000ms which is very short for a REST API, particularly when you're testing. Try this configuration in your application YML:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

Comment: Though it is working, why I am getting `Unknown property 'hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds'` in yml file ?

Comment: @BhushanPatil have you understood why you was getting this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I have resolved by using the prefer-id-address as true in my microservices configuration.

PS: Zuul couldn't resolve the DNS generated by the OS.

```
 eureka: 
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

Comment: This config resolved my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

change default to your registered app name

Comment: Please explain that further. What do you mean by "default"? That word is not present in the question

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to enable `CrossOrigin`.

You can use it as annotation like below:

```java
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class YourApplicationName{
....
}
```

Or with bean definition  like below:

```java
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```